# Grafana DataSource response data format

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datasource, grafana

I'm writing a fairly simple data source for Grafana and I'm having issues with the response to the query function usually located in datasource.js. I get this error message every time a query is made:

> Data source query result invalid, missing data field: undefined

As far as I understand, it's telling me that the data field in the returned object is undefined, but after printing the resulting response, I can see that it`s there and it's populated with data. Here is the code of the function in the Grafana data source.

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhUDw.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqppx.png)

Comment: The issue was the two chained http requests, the program did not wait for the last promise to be fulfilled, so it never got the data field

Comment: Great that you figured out it. Promises can be a pain sometimes. Why are you using HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET for a query?

Comment: The POST request is a one-time authentication request, when it is completed, only the sessionId is used and a single GET request is called on each query.

Comment: You should post your own comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the two chained http requests, the program did not wait for the last promise to be fulfilled, so grafana never got the data field.